# How do I select elements from the DOM using Mootools?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, selector

I'm new to Mootools and I'm stuck on the following problem.

I have this `ul` based menu.

```
<ul class="moo_mmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Trang Chu</span>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span>lv2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span>lv2</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using this mootools javascript code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {                
    var root = $$('.moo_mmenu');        
    var units = // !!! << here is my problem, see below :(
    units.setStyle('background-color' , 'blue');        
});
```

in the `units` variable I want to select all the `li` elements in the class `moo_mmenu` by using root varible, like

```
// jQuery
$('li', root);
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: I think first of all you will want `id` instead of `class`

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this reference on traversing DOM in mootools](http://ryanflorence.com/mootools-for-beginners-part-4-selecting-and-manipulating-dom-elements/)?

Comment: jQuery _$('li', root);_ is same as native javascript _root.getElementsByTagName('li')_ ? Why you want to use much slower jQuery or Mootools equivalent instead of much faster native javascript?

Comment: @Slomojo: i see `id` faster than `class`. But, this case i want using `class` ^^.

@Brad Christie: thanks for the link, it's useful :).

@Andrew: i using jQuery for my work for 3 years, but i really understand native js much. i see, jQuery syntax very different native js. now i want to learn mootools as a intermediate tool :). ^^

Comment: @Rueta - I'd agree with Andrew that using the *native* DOM API methods are likely to be more performant than using JQuery or Mootools, as they may carry a significant overhead, just how much depends on your usage. However, you should profile both methods if you have speed issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `id="moo_mmenu"`

```
var units = $$('#moo_mmenu li');
```

Will work fine.

If you really want to use `class="moo_mmenu"` (and I really don't think you do.) you can do this...

```
var units = $$('.moo_mmenu li');
```

If you need to get the `li` elements directly from the `root` var you can do.

```
root.getElements('li');
```

Comment: oh, third case is the perfect answer for me :). Thanksyou! :D